# MySQL y ANDROID, JDBC Connector, ¿Como realizar un HANDSHAKE correcto?

Tags: android, android-studio, encriptación, ssl

Estoy liado con mi proyecto de fin de grado e intento conectar mi App de android con mi servidor remoto MySQL. Uno de los requisitos es que esté cifrada la conexión. Para ello he activado SSL en el servidor MySQL y le he generado un TrustStore.

Me he descargado ese TrustStore y lo he añadido a mi proyecto en android. Desde android tengo el siguiente código usando el Connector/J que me proporciona MySQL:

```
try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion, usuario, contrasena);

        if (!conexion.isClosed()) {
            Toast.makeText(ShowsEverywhereApplication.getContext(), "¡CONEXIÓN ESTABLECIDA CON LA BASE DE DATOS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ShowsEverywhereApplication.getContext(), "¡La conexión no ha podido ser establecida...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowsEverywhereApplication.getContext(), "ERROR EN LA CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowsEverywhereApplication.getContext(), "ERROR EN LA CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowsEverywhereApplication.getContext(), "ERROR EN LA CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ShowsEverywhereApplication.getContext(), "ERROR EN LA CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS: \n" + e.getSQLState() + "\n\n" + "Código de error: " + e.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Ahora lo que quiero saber es.. que tengo que hacer con el almacén de claves del servidor, ya que he creado un usuario en MySQL que solo se puede conectar mediante SSL, y no tengo ni idea de como realizar esta conexión desde android con SSL... La conexión se realiza pero me da el error '08S01' desde la base de datos, es decir, error indicativo de que no puede realizar el HandShake del SSL correctamente, y claro, es porque en la parte de android me falta algo..